# Excluding posts from menu wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to exclude multiple posts from the menu by the wp_nav_menu exclude parameter but that does not work the way I want it. Only page with id 58 is excluded If I run the following lines of code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'exclude' => '58, 59, 60',
        'fallback_cb' => 'bfa_page_menu' 
    ) ); ?>
```

If I pass the IDs as an array the menu just crashes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered here http://9-sec.com/2012/10/how-to-exclude-pages-from-wp_nav_menu-2/

The other option is to use a custom walker function.